# When using Get-ADUser -Filter {}, process is slow

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-4.0

I am trying to clear out some orphaned user shares on a DFS share. I want to compare the full name of the folder to the `HomeDirectory` property of a specified object using `Get-ADUser -Filter`.

If I use for instance `(Get-ADUser $varibale -Properties * | Select Homedirectory)` I get an error displayed when the account is not found. So I used `-Filter` to hide the error if there is no account found. However, this is much slower than the `-Properties * | Select` method.

Script:

```
$path = Read-Host -Prompt "Share path...."
$Dirs = Get-ChildItem $Path

foreach ($D in $Dirs) {
    $Login = Get-ADUser -Filter {HomeDirectory -eq $d.FullName}

    if ($d.FullName -ne $Login."HomeDirectory") {
        $host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle = "Checking $d..."
        $choice = ""
        Write-Host "Comparing $($d.FullName)......." -ForegroundColor Yellow
        $prompt = Write-Host "An account with matching Home Directory to $($d.FullName) could not be found. Purge $($d.fullname)?" -ForegroundColor Red
        $choice = Read-Host -Prompt $prompt
        if ($choice -eq "y") {
            function Remove-PathToLongDirectory {
                Param([string]$directory)

                # create a temporary (empty) directory
                $parent = [System.IO.Path]::GetTempPath()
                [string] $name = [System.Guid]::NewGuid()
                $tempDirectory = New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path (Join-Path $parent $name)

                robocopy /MIR $tempDirectory.FullName $directory
                Remove-Item $directory -Force
                Remove-Item $tempDirectory -Force
            }
            # Start of Script to delete folders from User Input and Confirms
            # the specified folder deletion
            Remove-PathToLongDirectory $d.FullName
        }
    } else {
        Write-Host "Done!" -ForegroundColor Cyan
    }
    Write-Host "Done!" -ForegroundColor Cyan
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't make any sense. You're fetching the account that has a given directory as its home directory, but only do something when the account doesn't have that directory as its home directory. Which obviously will never happen. Also, why are you mirroring the directory to a temp directory and then delete both directories? And you shouldn't nest function definitions in a loop.

Comment: Also, we recommend against using `-Properties *` with `Get-ADUser`. That introduces unnecessary overhead.

Comment: Correction: your comparison will work, but only because you omitted `-Properties HomeDirectory` from the `Get-ADUser` call. The property is not returned by default, so `$Login."HomeDirectory"` will evaluate to `$null`, which doesn't equal `$d.FullName`. Still, the check is pointless and its logic is broken.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers, The reason for the comparison is we have some users who's login names have changed and they do not match the login name used to create the home share originally. (ex \\server\share\JDOE where JDOE changed thier login to JANED1 but the homedirectory in AD still points to \\server\share\JDOE.

As for the Function nesting. I am aware I need to move that.

Comment: Was also suggested that using MIR with robocopy will speed up the deletion process by creating an empty directory, copying the empty directory to the target directory then deleting both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of suboptimal things in your code (like (re-)defining a function inside a loop, or creating and deleting an empty directory over and over), but your biggest bottleneck is probably that you do an AD query for each directory. You should be able to speed up your code considerably by making a single AD query and storing its result in an array:

```
$qry   = '(&(objectclass=user)(objectcategory=user)(homeDirectory=*)'
$homes = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter $qry -Properties HomeDirectory |
         Select-Object -Expand HomeDirectory
```

so that you can check if there is an account with a given home directory like this:

```
foreach ($d in $dirs) {
  if ($homes -notcontains $d.FullName) {
    # ... prompt for deletion ...
  } else {
    # ...
  }
}
```

Performance-wise I didn't notice a difference between the `robocopy /mir` approach and `Remove-Item` when deleting a 2 GB test folder with each command. However, if you have paths whose [length exceeds 260 characters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247.aspx#maxpath) you should probably stick with `robocopy`, because `Remove-Item` [can't handle those](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/12179.net-powershell-path-too-long-exception-and-a-net-powershell-robocopy-clone.aspx). I would recommend adding a comment explaining what you're using the command for, though, because the next person reading your script is probably as confused about it as I was.

```
$empty = Join-Path ([IO.Path]::GetTempPath()) ([Guid]::NewGuid())
New-Item -Type Directory -Path $empty | Out-Null

foreach ($d in $dirs) {
  if ($homes -notcontains $d.FullName) {
    # ... prompt for confirmation ...
    if ($choice -eq 'y') {
      # "mirror" an empty directory into the orphaned home directory to
      # delete its content. This is used b/c regular PowerShell cmdlets
      # can't handle paths longer than 260 characters.
      robocopy $empty $d.FullName /mir
      Remove-Item $d -Recurse -Force
    }
  } else {
    # ...
  }
}

Remove-Item $empty -Force
```

There's also a [PowerShell module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PSAlphaFS) built on top of the AlphaFS library that supposedly can handle long paths. I haven't used it myself, but it might be worth a try.

Comment: Still new to this and to the website. In the future I'll try to be more clear about my questions and definitely make more commenting in my scripts. Thanks.